# Count symbols/punctuation in tweets

Tags: python, pandas

From a pandas dataframe, I would need to count punctuations by sentiment.
The data is

```
Tweet                                                        Sentiment
Once upon a time, in the middle of nowhere, ... !                 0
What are you f*** do?                                             -1
It's a lovely day!! :)                                           1
```

My desired output would be

```
Tweet                                                        Sentiment        Punctuation_count
Once upon a time, in the middle of nowhere, ... !                 0            6
What are you f*** do?                                             -1           4
It's a lovely day!! :)                                           1             5
```

If I wanted to remove punctuation, I would used:

`df["Punctuation"] = df['Tweet'].str.replace('[^\w\s]','')`

But what I would like to do is count the punctuation in each Tweet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to simply count the number of times elements in each string appear in `string.punctuation`:

```
import string
df['Punctuation_count'] = df['Tweet'].apply(lambda x: sum(el in string.punctuation for el in x))
```

Output:

```
                                               Tweet  Sentiment  Punctuation_count
0  Once upon a time, in the middle of nowhere, ... !          0                  6
1                              What are you f*** do?         -1                  4
2                             It's a lovely day!! :)          1                  5
```

Comment: @Val that probably means you have missing values (i.e. NaN) in that column. Check df.Tweet.isna().sum() and see if it’s nonzero.